# Add one time welcome screen in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have created a welcome screen in my app which i want to show at the start of the first time launch. Now i am using AsyncStorage to store value on first time and use that value to render homepage or welcome page. It is presently like this:

```js
    componentDidMount() {
           AsyncStorage.getItem('first_time').then((value) => {
           this.setState({ showRealApp: !value, loading: false });
     });
    

  
  if (this.state.showRealApp === true) {
    return (
            <View>
              <Text>Welcome Page</Text>
            </View>
        )}
  else {
   return (
       <Home/>
      )
  }
        
}
```

Now this works okay. But my welcome page doesn't have any header, but homepage does. So, when it shows the homepage, the header is missing. How can i get the header. I am using react navigation header for both. Also both the screens are on my stack navigator. My welcome page header is null but homepage header is not. How can i show the header of the homepage with this. Here's my stack navigator:

```js
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        FirstTimePage: { screen: FirstTimePage },
        Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
        ListAllScreen: { screen: ListAllScreen },
        DetailScreen: { screen: DetailScreen },
        CategoryScreen: { screen: CategoryScreen },
        ReviewsScreen: { screen: ReviewsScreen },
        NotificationScreen: { screen: NotificationScreen },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't properly navigate to the Home page use navigation.navigate('Home')

```
class FirstTimePage extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount() {
            AsyncStorage.getItem('first_time').then((value) => {
            this.setState({ showRealApp: !value, loading: false });
        });  
    }
    render(){
        const {navigation} = this.props;
        
        if (this.state.showRealApp === true) {
            return (
                    <View>
                        <Text>Welcome Page</Text>
                    </View>
            )
        }
        else {
            navigation.navigate('Home');
        }
    }
}
```